# Descendent and Child Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why are the "`a` tags" classified as descendants and not children? They look like they could be children rather than descendants. However, both lines of code below affect them the same way.

```
<p class="note">
  This page was written by
  <a href="mailto:ivy@example.com">ivy@example.com</a>
  <a href="http://www.example.com</a>
</p>
```

When I use the child selector:

```
p a {
  color: green;
}
```

`a` tags are green

When I use the descendant selector:

```
p > a {
  color: green;
}
```

`a` tags are green

What makes a descendant a descendant and a child a child?

Comment: You've got your selector names mixed up. `>` is the child selector. In your case, the only descendants are children, so there is no difference. Wrap one of the anchors in a `span` or something and watch one of the selectors stop working.

Comment: Children are a subset of descendants. Both selectors work because the `a` elements are both children and descendants.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, all the elements inside the `p` container are both children and descendants, so the child and descendant combinators will render the same output.

If your HTML looked like this:

```
<p class="note">
   This page was written by
   <a href="mailto:ivy@example.com"><span style="color: blue">ivy@example.com</span></a>
   <a href="http://www.example.com</a>
</p>
```

… then the `span` element would be a descendant of the `p` container, but not a child.

Think of a normal family. Parents have children. They are both children (`>`) and descendants () of the parents. The children then have children. These are descendants () of the original parents, but not their children (`>`).

Put another way, a child element is always a descendant, but a descendant is not always a child.

---

Spec reference:

> [**2. Selectors**](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors)
>
> `E F` means an F element descendant of an E element
>
> `E > F` means an F element child of an E element

Answer (score 0):

If you use `p a` then style is applied to all `a` elements, that are inside any `p` element.

If you use `p > a` then style is applied to all `a` elements, which `parent` is `p` element.

---

For example, if you have
`<p> <h1> <a> something </a> </h1> <p>`  (don't mind sense of that DOM structure)
then `a` element is not targetted by `p > a`, but is targetted by `p a`.

---

You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).